# Python-Micropython TCP sockets on w5100s-EVB-Pico

Tags: python, sockets, micropython

I have a [W5100S-EVB-Pico](https://www.wiznet.io/product-item/w5100s-evb-pico/) which is basically a Pi Pico with an ethernet port. I would like to send commands to it over a TCP socket connection. Basically I want to control hardware over ethernet using this board.

- The W5100 board should be a server that accepts connections/commands.
- I plan on programming a GUI in Python to send commands
- I'm running [this micropython version](https://github.com/Wiznet/RP2040-HAT-MicroPython/releases/tag/v1.0.5) on it.
- Python version 3.7

But this is the problem now:   The code below keeps giving me this error: '**OSError: [Errno 107] ENOTCONN**'

- EDIT_01: It seems like I'm closing the connection too soon from the client side ()
- EDIT_02: Do I need some kind of acknowledgement from the server before closing? Or, what are possible ways to implement this kind of communication?

Thanks for reading!

Here's the code and an explanation of what's going on:

The code on the W5100-EVB-Pico:

```
from machine import Pin, SPI
import network
import usocket as socket

# Only needed for static IP setup:
ip_address = '192.168.1.20'
subnet = '255.255.255.0'
gateway = '192.168.1.1'
dns = '8.8.8.8'

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_port = 8080

# Init ethernet
def init_ethernet():
    spi = SPI(0, 2_000_000, mosi=Pin(19), miso=Pin(16), sck=Pin(18))
    nic = network.WIZNET5K(spi, Pin(17), Pin(20))
    # Static IP:
    # nic.ifconfig((ip_address, subnet, gateway, dns))
    # DHCP:
    nic.active(True)

    while not nic.isconnected():
        pass
    
    ip_address = nic.ifconfig()[0]
    subnet     = nic.ifconfig()[1]
    gateway    = nic.ifconfig()[2]
    dns        = nic.ifconfig()[3]

    print('Connected:')
    print('IP        ', ip_address)
    print('Subnet    ', subnet)
    print('Gateway   ', gateway)
    print('DNS       ', dns)
    
    listen()
    
    
def listen():
    server_socket.bind((ip_address, socket_port))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    
    print(f'Listening on {ip_address} port {socket_port}')
    
    while True:
        print('>>>This should print once and it does')
        print('>>>Waiting for connection')
        client, address = server_socket.accept()
        print(f'Client connected from: {address}')
        client.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_ethernet()
```

The output when running this is:

```
netif changed  192.168.1.20
Connected:
IP         192.168.1.20
Subnet     255.255.255.0
Gateway    192.168.1.1
DNS        192.168.1.150
Listening on 192.168.1.20 port 8080
>>>This should print once and it does
>>>Waiting for connection
```

My Python code:

```
import socket

local_IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 8080

server_ip = '192.168.1.20'
server_port = 8080
server_address = (server_ip, server_port)


def test_socket():

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect(server_address)
        message = 'Hello from client'
        s.sendall(bytes(message, encoding="utf-8"))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_socket()
```

As soon as I run this code the output from the W5100 is:

```
...
>>>This should print once and it does
>>>Waiting for connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 55, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 37, in init_ethernet
  File "<stdin>", line 49, in listen
OSError: [Errno 107] ENOTCONN
```

=============================================

- EDIT_01:
  I found that when I add 'time.sleep(1)' here:

```
s.sendall(bytes(message, encoding="utf-8"))
time.sleep(1)
s.close()
```

The error does not occur. Am I closing the socket too soon on the Python side?

=============================================

- EDIT_02:

I changed this code on the server:

```
    while True:
        print('>>>Waiting for connection')
        client, address = server_socket.accept()
        print(f'Client connected from: {address}')
        data = client.recv(1024).decode()
        print(data)
        client.close()
```

And this on the client:

```
def test_socket():

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(server_address)
    message = 'This is a really long message of many bytes and can\n' \
              'even be some very long JSON data?\n' \
              'which is pretty awesome!\n' \
              'Man This is what I was after !!!'
    s.sendall(bytes(message, encoding="utf-8"))
    time.sleep(1)
    s.close()
```

However, time.sleep(1) is not the way to go :(

I think I should close the socket after an acknowledgement from the server?
Any hint and tips are welcome,
Thanks!

Comment: I found that when I add 'time.sleep(1)' in between 's.sendall()' and 's.close()' it seems to (sort of) work? Is my Python script closing the socket too soon?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the key seems to be error catching in the communication.

This client code works like intended... for now.

```
import socket
import json

local_IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 8080

server_ip = '192.168.1.20'
server_port = 8080
server_address = (server_ip, server_port)

commands = [['A', 1, '1234567890_1234567890_1234567890'],
            ['B', 2, 'hello'],
            ['C', 3.7],
            ['D', 4]]

def test_socket():

    for c in commands:
        send(json.dumps(c))


def send(message):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(server_address)

    s.sendall(bytes(message, encoding="utf-8"))

    try:
        received_data, addr = s.recvfrom(128)
        print(received_data, addr)
        print(received_data.decode('utf-8'))
    except socket.error as error:
        print(f'Socket error: {error.errno}')
    finally:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_socket()
```